# uninstall dialogs

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project, uninstallation

I am composing a setup project in VS2010 . I want to add a dialog with checkbox for the user to specify if he wants to delete the database or not. But I can't figure out how to do it: the user interface doesn't represent the uninstall dialogs on the "view dialogs" form. So I can show a messagebox instead, but then there is another problem: how can a person specify whether the database should be deleted or not if the uninstaller is launched in a quited mode? In that case some parameters should be passed to the setup project somehow. Got any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Right now I am trying to use Orca, it is a part of Windows Installer SDK.
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=A55B6B43-E24F-4EA3-A93E-40C0EC4F68E5&displaylang=en
It might solve my problem.